# Finding smallest delta available for permutations of a set of numbers

Tags: java, combinations, combinatorics

Presume we have a set of 12 objects, lets say {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}. We must break this set into 4 smaller ones composed of three objects, so that the largest sum and smallest sum of these four sets is minimized. We must find this difference. In our example, {1,7,12},(3,8,9},{4,5,10},{2,6,11}. These four sets satisfy the problem since their sums are 20 and 19, meaning a delta of 1, our answer.

How can one solve this problem for any arbitrary 12 values?

I've tried enumerating all partitions of said set into 4 sets of 3, and finding one with the optimal score. However, time is of the essence, and so I was wondering how one would approach this problem in Java

I don't have exact code on me right now, but what it essentially was was 9 nested for loops, where the first three that nest are one set, the next three are the next set, the last three are another set, and the three left overs are another set. I used a 2D array so that values would be in score[i][0] and score[i][1] would act as an indicator to let me know if that value in score[i][0] had already been placed into a set.

This of course gets tedious and inefficient.

Comment: Please post any code you have developed so far. People asking for help here must demonstrate a reasonable effort to solve the problem on their own.  It even more essential for homework assignments.

Comment: Not really a homework assignment, just something I've been thinking about.

Comment: But yeah give me a second.

Comment: Yeah, right... And that's why "*time is of essence*" on Sunday night?

Comment: By time is of the essence, I mean to say that I want to know if there are better ways to approach this problem so that it is more resourceful with time. The approach that I used basically lists out all possible 4-sets of 12 and essentially tests it for the change. Save that change to a local variable, make more 4-sets and if the new set is smaller, set that to be the output. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: @user3188465: my approach ain't working AFAICT.   Consider *(2 25 28)  (5 17 33)  (7 14 35)  (11 21 23)*

Comment: Bleh I just got back on and was going to see if I could implement your version of a solution, but yeah. Perhaps there are only certain special cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily simplify the problem by finding the values that the sums must approach for a better optimisation :

For instance, in your simple case (1,2...12), then the total sum of every terms is 78. Thus, Each groups must have a sum very close to 78/4=19.

So, let's try a very simple algorithm :

```
- compute TOTAL_SUM = SUM(terms)
- compute TARGET_SUM = TOTAL_SUM / number(terms)
- set DELTA=0
- loop {
-    Try to split terms in groups where TARGET_SUM - DELTA <= SUM <= TARGET_SUM + DELTA
-    if a solution is found, exit
-    DELTA = DELTA + 1
-    }
```

Ok, I did not helped you much with this "Try to split..." step. But it should look like you own solution, except that you have additional constraints which can help you to speed up the process.

Hope this helps.

Comment: great idea - this solution makes sense, and the "splitting" shouldn't be too hard to implement.